# C# Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement. Am I not seeing something?

Tags: c#, sql, oledb, insert-into

I'm having a hard time with this SQL Insert command. I've written other insert commands that work fine, but this one keeps giving me an error that says "Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement." Can somebody help me see what I'm missing?

```
        bool recordSaved;

        // Opens a connection to the database

        OleDbParameter param = new OleDbParameter();
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + Path + "");
        conn.Open();
        OleDbCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();

        string strSQL;

        command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Password", Password));
        command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@FName", FName));
        command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@LName", LName));
        command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Street", StreetAddress));
        command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@City", City));
        command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@State", State));
        command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Zip", Zip));
        command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Phone", PhoneNumber));
        command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@CCType", CCType));
        command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@CCNum", CCNumber));

        // Inserts a new user record into the database
        strSQL = "INSERT INTO tblUser (Password, FName, LName, StreetAddress, City, State, Zip, PhoneNumber, CCType, CCNumber) " +
            "VALUES (@Password, @FName, @LName, @Street, @City, @State, @Zip, @Phone, @CCType, @CCNum)";            

        // Stores the strSQL insert statement into a command object
        command.CommandText = strSQL;

        // Executes the insert statement
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        command.Parameters.Clear();

        // Closes the connection to the database
        conn.Close();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like Password might be your problem. Try putting parentheses around it INSERT INTO tblUser ([Password]. From what I just read its a reserved word for the jet.oledb.

Comment: MS Access: everytime a shame! ;)